# How database system comes to know how many different values a particular column has?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

At following link

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/selectivity-in-sql-databases/

the author has written that since "SEX" column has only two possible values thus its selectivity for 10000 records would be; according to formula given; 0.02 %.

But my question that how a database system come to know that this particular column has this many unique values? Wouldn't the database system require scanning the entire table at least once? or some other way the database system would come to know about those unique values?

Answer (score 4):

First, you are applying the formula wrong.  The selectivity for sex (in the example given) would be 50% not 0.02%.  That means that each value appears about 50% of the time.

The general way that databases keep track of this is using something called "statistics".  These are measures that are kept about all tables and used by the optimizer.  Sometimes, the information can also be provided by an index on the column.

Comment: I think selectivity as used here is more a measure of _how useful is the index in helping to find the required records_, So this depends on the number of records. Thus, if there were only 2 records and two distinct values, the selectivity would be 100%, 2 records and 1 value (e.g. both female) would give you a selectivity of a half. 100 records (all female) would give you a selectivity of 1%

Comment: @Loopo . . . Here is an example of how I understand selectivity and how it is normally applied to indexes and databases (http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq167/).

Comment: Yes, in that article, a distinction is made between _index 'statistics'_ and _selectivity_

Answer (score 1):

Comming back to your actual question: Yes, the database scans all table data frequently and saves some statistics, (e.g. max value, min value, number of distinct keys, number of rows in a table, etc.) in a internal table. These statistics are used to **estimate** the basic result of your query (or other DML operations) in order to evalutat the optimal execution plan. You can manually trigger generation of statistic by running command `EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_DATABASE_STATS;` or some of the [other ones](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i996857). You can advise Oracle also to read only a sample of all data (e.g. 10% of all rows)

Usually data content does not change drastically, so it does not matter if the numbers are not absolutly exact, they are (usually) sufficient to estimate an execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has many processes related to calculating the number of distinct values (NDV).

1. **Manual Statistics Gathering:** Statistics gathering can be triggered manually, through many different procedures in DBMS_STATS.
2. **AUTOTASK:**  Since 10g Oracle has a default AUTOTASK job, "auto optimizer stats collection".  It will only gather statistics if the current stats are stale.
3. **Bulk Load:** In 12c statistics can be gathered [during a bulk load](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_statscon.htm#TGSQL344).
4. **Sample:** The NDV can be computed from 100% of the data or can be estimated based on a sample.  The sample can be either based on blocks or rows.
5. **One-pass distinct sampling:** 11g introduced a [new AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE algorithm](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_does_auto_sample_size).  It scans the entire table but only uses one pass.  It's much faster to scan the whole table than to have to sort even a small part of it.  There are several more in-depth descriptions of the algorithm, such as [this one](http://jonathanlewis.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/one-pass-distinct-sampling-presentation.pdf).
6. **Incremental Statistics:** For partitioned tables Oracle can store extra information about the NDV, called a synopsis.  With this information, if only a single partition is modified, only that one partition needs to be analyzed to generate both partition and global statistics.
7. **Index NDV:** Index statistics are created by default when an index is created.  Also, the information can be periodically re-gathered from DBMS_STATS.GATHER_INDEX_STATS or the cascade option in other procedures in DBMS_STATS.
8. **Custom Statistics:** The NDV can be manually set with DBMS_STATS.SET_* or ASSOCIATE STATISTICS.
9. **Dynamic Sampling:** Right before a query is executed, Oracle can automatically sample a small number of blocks from the table to estimate the NDV.  This usually only happens when statistics are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Database scans the data set in a table so it can use the most efficient method to retrieve data. Database measures the uniqueness of values using the following formula:

```
Index Selectivity = number of distinct values / the total number of values
```

The result will be between zero or one. Index Selectivity of zero means that there are not any unique values. In these cases indexes actually reduce performance. So database uses sequential scanning instead of seek operations.
For more information on indexes read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42553/index-seek-vs-index-scan